# Fatal error: Call to a member function get_row()

Tags: php

I'm working for admin login please anybody fix that..

`Email: <?php echo $admin->get_email(); ?>`

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get_row() on a non-object in D:\MyWebSite\business_design\admin\admin-class.php on line 82
```

The code:

```
public function get_email() {
        $username = $_SESSION['admin_login'];
        global $db;
        $info = $db->get_row("SELECT `email` FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '" . $db->escape($username) . "'");
        if(is_object($info))
            return $info->email;
        else
            return '';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay, are you using a framework?
Your `$db` variable is not instantiated, so when you call `$db->get_row`:

1. PHP can't find the `$db` object; and so,
2. `get_row()` can't exist.

Comment: You need to instantiate your $db with the Class that control your DB connection or so with the class that have the get_row() function.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, make sure you know which class $db should be referring to. The same class will have the function "get_row"

First you have to include that class file in your php scrip file. That can be done easily by following script -

```
function __autoload($class_name){
    require_once("RELATIVE_ADDRESS_OF_THE_CLASS".$class_name.".php");
}
```

Say for example you have your class is Database, so you should first instantiate $db as below -

```
$db = new Database();
```

Later if all the scripts are working properly in "Database" class, it should work straightaway...

Hope it helps..